# Setting-up CORS - 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cors, omniauth, same-origin-policy

I'm fairly new to coding and am learning about Devise/Omniauth at the moment. I'm working on a tutorial to get a user to connect with Facebook through Omniauth as an example but get the following error in the console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I understand that for security reasons, some browsers are not allowing CORS request. I did find many related topics on StackOverflow ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613210/cors-access-control-allow-origin-despite-correct-headers), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709790/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134117/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-an?rq=1),[link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome?lq=1),[link5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310112/why-am-i-seeing-an-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-error?lq=1)) and that the main thing is to allow

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

I tried it and couldn't get it to work. Because I'm using ruby, I also found out that there is a gem called ([Rack-Cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors)) to allow CORS requests with ruby and thought to myself "Cool, I'm saved" but I couldn't get it to work either.

Running out of option and because I'm running Chrome, I also tried to open chrome that way

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --disable-web-security
```

It didn't work either. I tried different things for the past days and cannot get the Omniauth Facebook login to work (PS: I have allowed access to http://localhost:3000/ in the Facebook developers settings page of my app)

Please find enclosed the link to my repository on Github:
[repository](https://github.com/GBouffard/yelp_clone)

What a I doing wrong? Are there some specific way to set-up CORS that I'm missing? If anyone could help or know how to make it work with ruby/chrome, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rack-cors gem to solve the problem

We have already talked before similar problems it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177079/how-to-send-cors-headers-with-devise-if-user-not-authorized-401-response)